# Compute the corresponding decile for each value in a vector

Tags: r, quantile

is there a quick way in R to assign to each value in a given vector the corresponding decile ?

For example an arbitrary input vector should be transformed like the following.

```
in  <- rnorm(10)

>  [1]  9  2 10  5  3  4  8  1  7  6
```

cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `quantile` function to get the deciles

```
deciles = quantile(ran, seq(0, 1, 0.1))
```

Then use `cut` to put your data into the correct deciles

```
ran_dec = cut(ran, deciles, include.lowest = TRUE)
```

Since `ran_dec` is a factor, just use

```
as.numeric(ran_dec)
```

to convert to a number.

Comment: A similar option is `findInterval(ran, deciles, all.inside=TRUE)` (nice  plus one)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use dplyr's `ntile` function easily:

```
dplyr::ntile(rnorm(10), 10)
# [1] 10  5  2  1  9  3  4  8  7  6
```